# How to get the latest date from array in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

I have an array of dates. I need to find the latest one. Can someone show me an example?

Comment: What have you already done to try to solve this? What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make `NSDate` conform to `Comparable`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29455824/sort-array-of-dictionaries-by-nsdates-within-the-dictionaries/29457039#29457039)

Given this, you can then use `maxElement` to find the maximum (i.e. the latest).

```
import Foundation

extension NSDate: Comparable { }

public func ==(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.isEqualToDate(rhs)
}

public func <(lhs: NSDate, rhs: NSDate) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .OrderedAscending
}

let dates = [NSDate(), NSDate()]

let maxDate = maxElement(dates)
```

Note, `maxElements` goes bang for empty arrays so you may want to guard it with `isEmpty`:

```
let maxDate = dates.isEmpty ? nil : Optional(maxElement(dates))
```

Or, if you don’t want to go the extension route:

```
if let fst = dates.first {
    let maxDate = dropFirst(dates).reduce(fst) {
        $0.laterDate($1)
    }
}
```

or, to return an optional:

```
let maxDate = dates.reduce(nil) {
  (lhs: NSDate?, rhs: NSDate?)->NSDate? in
    lhs.flatMap({rhs?.laterDate($0)}) ?? rhs
}
```

Comment: A great answer to a poor question.

Comment: Great answer, but watch out for this inscrutable bug with maxElement and archiving: http://hern.as/code/minelement-segmentation-fault-while-compiling-swift/

Answer (score 5):

You can make use of `reduce`:

```
guard let dates = dates, !dates.isEmpty else { return nil }
dates.reduce(Date.distantPast) { $0 > $1 ? $0 : $1 }
```

Edit: Handle empty or nil array

Comment: This doesn't work if you have an empty array of values (you would expect it to return nil)

Answer (score 3):

Swift has Array methods for getting both the min and max values for dates.

You can use the following:

- `let maxDate = myArrayOfDates.max()`
- `let minDate = myArrayOfDates.min()`

So if you have an array of dates like so:
[image]

And here is the code if you want to copy it:

```swift
let now = Date()

let dates = [
    now,
    now.addingTimeInterval(120),
    now.addingTimeInterval(60)
]

let sut = dates.max()
print(sut!)
```

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score -1):

Run this in your playground

```html
var dates = [NSDate]()

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
let date1 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("02-06-1987")
let date2 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("02-06-2001")
let date3 = dateFormatter.dateFromString("02-06-2010")

//var date1 = NSDate()
dates.append(date3!)
dates.append(date1!)
dates.append(date2!)


var maxDate = dates[0]
for i in 0...dates.count-1
{
    if(maxDate.compare(dates[i]).rawValue == -1){
        maxDate = dates[i]
        println(maxDate)
    }
    println(maxDate)
}

println(maxDate.description)
```

have a good day :)